# Woocommerce buttons, grey area at bottom and filling entire screen

Tags: css, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

I have a number of issues with my woocommerce pages in my wordpress site that I am hoping someone could help me with. They have been driving me crazy trying to fix.

My theme - Trias - http://www.mojo-themes.com/item/trias-multi-style-corporate-responsive-theme/  does not support woocommerce and this has creatd issues.

1. First one is the woocommerce pages - category and product fill the entire screen i.e. right to the edge. Any idea how I would change this to be in line with my theme?
2. At the bottom of these woocommerce category and product pages - the theme ends and you can see grey area beneath the theme area - any ideas on how to prevent this.
3. Final query and this one is the most annoying - the theme has a floating icon on buttons i.e. a floating small arrow on the left of the arrow before the words start. Problem is on the woocommerce pages - the floating arrow floats above the words on the button. It is super annoying.

My themes button is as:

```
button,
a.button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 0 none;
/*  background: #00a3da url("images/button-link-arrow.png") no-repeat 0 50%;*/
    padding: 7px 12px 7px 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Oswald";
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
```

Please see image of the button with floating arrow: [image of button with incorrect floating arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcbw6.jpg)

Thank you very much in advance for any suggestions at all

Comment: Hi - Link is https://waster.com.au/product-category/commingle-recycle-service/

Comment: Strange is like rules are not applied on single product page… Updated my answer for individual product pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*— U P D A T E D —*

Add this CSS rules to the `style.php` file of your active child theme or theme

For your icon buttons :

```css
.button.product_type_variable.add_to_cart_button, 
.single_add_to_cart_button.button,  
button.single_add_to_cart_button, 
.button.wc-forward {
    padding-left: 34px !important;
}
.button.product_type_variable.add_to_cart_button:before, 
.single_add_to_cart_button.button:before,
button.single_add_to_cart_button:before, 
.button.wc-forward:before {
    top: 6px !important;
}
```

For your content (only woocommerce pages):

```css
.woocommerce .content-wrap {
    width: 934px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 36px;
}
```

You will have to add custom media queries and adapt the values of this rules depending on target screen resolutions.

I think that you haven't set correctly your pages (regarding your theme), that's why you have this kind of "content" problems on woocommerce pages:

**The best way to solve this kind of issue is to contact author's theme support threads, opening a ticket.**

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec - can I ask another query -

Comment: Thanks LoicTheAztec - can I ask another query - 1. are you able to tell me the code to change the buttons on the individual product pages and also the view cart buttons and the place order button. Regarding the content wrap above - can I use it only on the woocommerce pages? Thankyou very much.

Comment: Thanks Loic - this answer has pretty much solved the query and I have accepted it. For some reason though the arrows are still appearing on the individual product pages - https://waster.com.au/product/confidential-paper-240-litre-service/ and also on the view cart buttons. Would you be able to suggest how to adjust the code to fix those. Re the authors theme - they have stated the theme does not support woocommerce and left it at that. Thanks again for your help.